# Where to place the 's

Tags: apostrophe, writing

I have the following long sentence :

> If one of those promotions has a name that matches xxx, ...

I would rather write it shortly :

> If one of those' name matches xxx, ...

My question is : what to put after the 'those' and is it even a correct formulation ?

There can be only one promotion at a time that matches xxx.

*Note : I'm French, so many questions remains for me concerning English...*

Comment: Questions like this from non-native speakers are not appropriate here. (I see you have 3 close votes already, and I'd add one if I had not reached my daily limit). Try SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put apostrophe to 'those'. It has to be: "If one of those promotions' name matches...."

Comment: Thanks :) Do you know why did we get downvoted ?